# Upstart to Systemd porting

Tags: init, upstart, systemd

I have this line in an upstart conf file:

```
start on starting service1 or stopped service2
stop on stopping service1
```

How can this be translated to systemd unit target? I've searched for any kind of disjunction support but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When service2 is started, service1 should also be started. This relation can be implemented using `Requires`
In service2's unit config file, add

```
Requires=service1.service
```

But this will start both services in parallel when you run a command to start service2. To control the order in which the services start, you need to use `Before` or `After`

More on it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files)

Comment: Got it eventually. So you have 2 notions for systemd: dependency and ordering. The only predicates that establish ordering are "After" and "Before". If neither is specified a dependent service will be started in parallel with the one that sets the dependency. Thanks @t_thirupathi!

Comment: For the "or" I just use ExecStopPost in service2 with "systemctl start" cmd.